# regex value is between (but not including) 0 - 32

Tags: regex

my current regex:

```
/^[0-9]{3}$/
```

This will match if the value is an integer with a length of 2.

I need to expand this a bit further by matching only values between 0 - 32.

```
0 <- not match
1 <- match
2 <- match
...
29 <- match
30 <- match
32 <- not match
33 <- not match
```

Test your regex:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: `^(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])$` will do

Comment: @MSalters OP stated `0 <- not match`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov can you put your comment in an answer and tell me exactly what is happening? by the way it works.

Comment: Is `0` a match or not? Your title and example conflict...

Comment: if a number is between two numbers then 0 and 32 are not included.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, Putting your regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qV4xN2/2), it doesent seem to work there..

Comment: @JonasCz: you need to add the `gm` flags since you have more than one and multiple lines in the regex

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
/^((?:[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))$/
```

Test it in Python:

```
for i in range(0,321):
    m=re.match(r'^((?:[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))$', str(i))
    if m:
        print i
# prints 1-31...
```

Test in Bash / Perl:

```
$ echo {0..3500} | tr ' ' '\n' | perl -nle 'print $1 if /^((?:[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))$/'
prints 1-31
```

And test in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mK7sK3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Required regex can be formed like this

```
/^[1-9]$|^[1-2][0-9]$|^3[0-2]$/
```

Also, the given regex will match only 3 digit integers.

Comment: Seems like OP wants a regex to match 0 - 32, not a 3 digit integer..

Comment: Can you break the regex apart and describe what is happening? i need to be able to use this same statement for another number. I'm starting to think i cant do what im trying to do.

Comment: There are three parts in this regex. `^[1-9]$` matches any number between 1-9. `^[1-2][0-9]$` matces a number between 10 and 29. `^3[0-2]$` will match an integer between 30 and 32. You can try them separately. @JonasCz by "given regex" i meant the regex which is mentioned in the question.